# How can I display only the unique values in one column in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to display the unique values in a column ONLY?

**Example:**

```
AAPL
AAPL
AAPL
AAPL
AKAM
AMZN
AMZN
AMZN
AMZN
AMZN
AMZN
```

**Expected result:**

```
AAPL
AKAM
AMZN
```

I have already done a sort for multiple factors, and the first match for each is the best match.

I'm not sure if this is a vlookup or something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the data, make sure for a column that you have the first cell as a Label, Use an Advanced Filter and choose Unique Values only. You don't need to enter any criteria, just hit ok after checking the Unique Value box.

Comment: amazing..thank you...it worked perfectly.  Have a great day, Lance.

Comment: @Lance Roberts Can you explain a bit further ?

Comment: @HappyBird, ok, done.