# Unique values in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I display only the unique values in one column in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/264949/how-can-i-display-only-the-unique-values-in-one-column-in-excel)

I want remove equal words, not simply duplicate words, EQUAL words:

[image]

Comment: this isn't a duplicate question, unless you're reading impaired.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually sure I completely understand what exactly you are doing... but here's a simple answer anyway:

Assuming you will do the following in a separate column e.g Column C.

1. Write whatever variation of this IF statement that suits you: =IF(B1=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)),"")
   ==> this function simply returns a null string if a match is found, and the default value if not (you can obviously suppress the defaul value too or process it howwever you want)
2. Copy and Paste Column C onto itself using Paste Special| Values (only)
3. Delete Column B

This gives you the luxury of being able to quickly check if output is what you want

Comment: I want eliminate equal words..sorry for confusion..look this pic: http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/1651/equalwords.png

Answer (score 0):

Actually, lines are not important in your question.

Copy all cells with relevant data into column A of a new sheet.
Assuming you'll choose column A, start from A1.

Now type the following function staring at B1:

B1: `=CountIf(A:A,A1)`

Copy this function down in B, one for each row of data in A.

Only unique values in cells will count 1 in column B, all other B function cells will count more.

Sort columns A:B by B (Ascending), and delete all cells with a value larger than 1.

I hope it helps.

Comment: yes..thank you..the unique words are counted once,,but can u re-write again the formula please..is correctly? i press enter but give me an error..'Name?'